# PostgreSQL on Desktop vs. Server

Tags: postgresql, windows, postgresql-9.5, hardware

How does running PostgreSQL on a Windows desktop with pgAdmin III compare to running it on a dedicated server? I am trying to develop a database with very large tables (~60 million rows) with the following hardware:

- 64-bit Windows 7
- Dual quad-core Intel Core i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40 GHz
- 32 GB RAM

I would like to know if it would be worthwhile to invest in a server or whether the desktop should be sufficient. The tables will be static, so I mainly concerned with the time it will take to read the data and perform basic aggregate and join operations.

Comment: How can I improve the speed of the aggregate and join operations? It can sometimes take several minutes for them to finish. If you have any suggested resources, that would be very helpful! I can also ask this in another thread if that's more appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

<sub>*Wiki answer collecting partial answers originally left in question comments*</sub>

That's more than enough, you don't need a server.

60 million rows isn't that big nowadays - unless you've got huge numbers of blobs. Stick with your desktop unless you start to have major performance issues.

PostgreSQL runs better on *nix than on Windows and the number of drives is a big factor too. Nothing beats a ton of SSDs in RAID 10, but you'll be fine with your current setup!

If you want help improving your queries, you should post a question with the query and query plan from `explain (analyze)`. See [`postgresql-performance`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) for more details on which information is required for questions regarding slow queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can create you own benchmark (or just use the defaults) with pgbench. With pgbench you can measure the database performance in TPS (transactions per second) and then simulate a concurrently environment.

If you need a starting point for your PostgreSQL tuning, please take a look at pgconfig.org.

Please, take a look at the documentation, for more details about pgbench:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgbench.html